# Incapaz de quitar un espacio en java

Tags: java, php

Buenas,

Estoy intentando quitar con java un espacio. El valor lo obtengo a través de scraping, por ejemplo el valor `11 990,00`.

He intentado con:

`.replace(" ", "")`

`.replace("\\S", "")`

`.replace(" ", "z").replace("z", "")` Esto ya ha sido para probar si no me estaba captando el espacio bien.

Pues no hay manera...Ese valor lo introduzco después en una base de datos, y al recoger ese dato con PHP me sale el siguiente valor: `11�990.00`.

He intentado también quitarlo con PHP pero sin resultados usando el siguiente código:

`sub_str(" ", "",$posts[0]["$pais"])`

Pero me sigue sin quitar el espacio. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal. El ejemplo que estoy mostrando es del precio sacado de este [link](https://www.microsoft.com/hu-hu/store/p/alien-isolation/c1h9v6slk2k5).

Comment: ¿Podrías darnos el origen de la página? Parece ser que no es un espacio en blanco, sino un carácter (posiblemente un carácter vacío especial) que no ha podido ser convertido de un juego de caracteres a otro.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, el link está justo al final. En el HTML al editarlo aparece esto: `<span>11&nbsp;990,00 HUF áfával</span>`. Es decir `&nbsp;` que no sé ni qué es.

Comment: Lo he visto, y te he puesto varias soluciones. La más obvia era que recibieras el HTML directamente. Viendo que seguías igual te he puesto el problema, probablemente alguna función que has usado para obtener los datos ha modificado la codificación del texto, convirtiéndola en UNICODE por lo que veo en la respuesta de @Francute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pareciera ser que te está devolviendo un espacio duro. Probaste removerlo con `.replace("\u00a0","")`?

Comment: ¡Solucionado! No sabía ni de la existencia de los espacios duros, pero es el que me ha servido. Valido tu respuesta ahora.

Answer (score 4):

El contenido en HTML de la página te está devolviendo una entidad HTML `&nbsp;` que corresponde con un espacio en blanco que no puede romperse (en HTML varios espacios en blanco se unifican en uno, los espacios en blanco al comienzo o final de un párrafo se elimina, etc).

Debe ser reemplazada, por ejemplo, con `.replace(" ", "").replace("&nbsp;", " ")` o directamente con `.replace("&nbsp;", "")`.

Si quieres ser meticuloso al analizar páginas web, echa un vistazo a [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4-java.lang.String-) para hacer otras sustituciones de entidades HTML como  `&gt;` (`>`), `&lt;` (`<`), `&amp;` (`&`), etc.

Ten en cuenta que esa librería convierte por defecto a [ISO-8859-1](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#line.348), por lo que debes usar el equivalente en ISO de la entidad (`&nbsp;` se corresponde con el carácter 160 o `A0` en hexadecimal). Si usas otra que te lo convierta a UNICODE entonces el carácter es [`00A0` en hexadecimal](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) (en UNICODE los caracteres ocupan dos octetos).

Así, resumiendo, dependiendo del formato o juego de caracteres en el que esté la cadena:

- HTML: `.replace("&nbsp;", "")`
- ISO-8859-1: `.replace("\a0","")`
- UNICODE: `.replace("\u00a0","")`

Comment: Lo he intentado y me sigue dando el mismo resultado.

Comment: En algún momento hay algo que está modificando la cadena. ¿Qué usas para obtenerla?